# Can I use a #define representation of a stdlib function?

Tags: c, embedded, eclipse-cdt

I kinda liked the idea of having my own sprintf function without the string.h or stdio.h bloatware.

```c
#define sprintf(x)   my_sprintf(x)

void my_sprintf(const char * string);

int main(void)
{
  sprintf("abc");
}
```

These are my LD flags:

```
LDFLAGS += -lgcc
LDFLAGS += --specs=nano.specs
LDFLAGS += -mthumb
LDFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m4
# LDFLAGS += --gc-sections
# LDFLAGS += -nostartfiles 
# LDFLAGS += -nodefaultlibs
# LDFLAGS += -gc-sections
```

As you see, I have the nostartfiles and nodefaultlibs options unset. So, even if I had the idea of including string.h or stdio.h, The compiler might find a definition/reference of the sprintf function.

So I'd like to know what if the #define will still refer to the "redefinition" if it is the same than an existing function name.

Any help is warmly welcome.

Comment: `#define will still refer to the "redefinition" if it is the same than an existing function name.` I don't understand that. Why not just define your own function `sprintf` and let linker link with it? As you seem to be using gcc, you could consider just `attribute((alias))` the functions.

Comment: Just be careful so you don't change the semantics of the functions you "define" (like you do in the shown example). Also note that this will generally make your code harder to maintain and use for others (and with "others" include yourself a couple of years in the future).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Indeed.  The opportunities for future bugs from obfuscating a common standard C function are endless.  And "a couple of years" could very well arrive tomorrow...

Comment: I'd hardly call the C standard library "bloatware".  Boost, on the other hand...

Comment: In embedded systems it is bloatware imho

Comment: @KamilCuk: Per the fourth item in the list in C 2018 7.1.3 1, `sprintf` is reserved as an identifier with external linkage, regardless of whether the header that declares it is included. So, if you define a function named `sprintf`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. (The linker may choose the library, or the compiler may handle it specially.) However, `sprintf` is not reserved for use as a macro as long as the `<stdio.h>` header is not included. So defining a macro named `sprintf` that is replaced by a different identifier does not result in behavior not defined by the C standard.

Comment: It is possible, provided `<stdio.h>` header is not included **after** that macro definition. However whether your method is recommended is another matter.

Comment: Note that the first argument of `sprintf()` should normally be a modifiable character array, and you need a second argument that's a format string, optionally with extra arguments to provide values to be formatted.  If you're going to coopt the name of a standard function, keep its interface the same — you'll confuse everyone if you don't.  If you want a non-standard interface, use a non-standard name, too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is possible even if the `<stdio.h>` is included, provided it is **not** included after that macro definition.

Comment: @LxerLx: No, the standard makes no provision for that. If the header is included and the translation unit defines the `sprintf` macro, then the fifth item listed in 7.1.3 1 of the 2018 C standard says the standard does not define the behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No. That item starts with "Each identifier with file scope...". The identifier at that point (after expanding the macro in phase 4) is `my_sprintf` (not `sprintf`). Read also **6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers 1** : "Macro names and macro parameters are not considered further here...". Also read **7.1.2 Standard headers 4** : "...  it [the standard header] shall first be included before the first reference to any of the functions or objects it declares, or to any of the types or macros it defines.

Comment: A better idea is to forget that you ever saw stdio.h and write your own conversion routines from integer to string. Most often you don't need other number formats other than unsigned decimal fixed point. Then you can indeed replace the whole bloatware sprintf with a simple loop: `uint_fast8_t i; 
for(i=1; i<=length; i++) { str[length-i] = (char) ((val % 10ul) + '0'); val/=10ul;
} str[i-1] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but an easier way would be to use a freestanding environment:

```
gcc -ffreestanding ...
```

If you want to know if your approach will take effect across files (i.e. `#define function(x) y` in `file1.c` and `function(z)` in `file2.c`), then no, it won't.